# Passing a variable to redirect url_for in flask

Tags: python, flask

I was wondering if it is possible to pass a value through `redirect(url_for())` with out it becoming a `GET`.

*Basic example:* I have a home function:

```
@app.route("/")
def home(msg=None):
    return render_template("home.html", mgs=msg)
```

how can I pass an message to the home function?
In other words can I do this:

```
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return render_template('home.html', msg="logged out")
```

with `redirect(url_for())`?

this:

```
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('home', msg="logged out"))
```

just gives me the url with a get /?msg='logged out'.

I understand that url_for is generating an url based on the name of the function being passed to it. Can you pass a value to that function?

Comment: A gross (but not totally impractical) way would be to use a session variable, but other than that, No you cannot.

Comment: You can, *if* the URL is expecting that variable. So if your route was "/logout/:message", that would work, but then your URL would end up as "/logout/logged out" which would be even more horrible. (Although note there's nothing at all gross about using sessions; that's exactly what they're for.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about a flash variable?

```
flash("logged out")
return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

Then in template for `home`:

```
{% with passed = get_flash_messages() %}
{% if passed %}
    <!-- passed should contain 'logged out' -->
{% endif %}
```

see also: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/flashing/

Answer (score 3):

Another way to go is using **sessions**:

Dont forget to add it to your imports

`from flask import Flask, ..., session`

In `logout` definition store the message in the session:

```
@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    logout_user()
    session['msg'] = "logged out"
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

In the `home` function

```
@app.route("/")
def home(msg=None):
    return render_template("home.html", msg=session['msg'])
```

In the `home` template just use it as a usual variable:

`<p>Dear user, you have been {{ msg }} </p>`

This way you avoid using `get` and Flask takes care of all

Answer (score 0):

No, I Do not think so, but you can use GET parameters like:

```
redirect('home?msg=You%20are%20loged%20in')
```

and instead of using a template to do the work you can use JS

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use the value passed in the template. Seems messy using the GETs. (user can make page say what ever) I guess I'll just used render_template when needed.

Comment: I am not following here, What is wrong with the user changing the text that the page says?

Comment: nothing wrong, I was just trying to avoid using GETs

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
msg="logged out"
return redirect(url_for('home'),code=307)
```

Code 307 is used as "POST"

Answer (score 0):

Just use an `f-string` in your route direction.

```py
redirect(f'/route/{variable}')
```

Comment: There seems to be a missing closing parenthesis `)` in your answer.